# Display parent div only if populated with content

Tags: php, html, wordpress, if-statement, advanced-custom-fields

Is there a way to only display a parent (wrapping) if it's actually been populated with content?

The reason I ask is in Wordpress I'm using Advanced Custom Fields to create additional text areas on the homepage of the website. The content is added to the page inside divs, like this:

```
<section class="band">
    <div class="wrap">

        <?php the_field('services'); ?>

    </div>
</section>
```

If the field is left blank, obviously the markup that surrounds remains on the page and due to the margin/padding they have set on them it leaves a big empty stripe across the page.

I know little Wordpress (and PHP in general), I assume this must be possible? I've had a play around with if/else statements but had no luck.

Can anyone advise on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it this way:

```
<?php if( get_field('services') ) : ?>
    <section class="band">
        <div class="wrap">

            <?php the_field('services'); ?>

        </div>
    </section>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: That looks like it does the trick! Not that it's important now but if you were loading multiple `the_field` php calls in the same div, could you use this method as well?

Comment: You need to use `get_field()` since `the_field()` prints the value as opposed to returning it.

Comment: To answer your question: yes, but you would need to check against each value separately.

Comment: If that solution works, please accept the answer. Thanks!